# Add current date and developer name to method header

Tags: visual-studio-2010, header, auto-generate

I am using Visual Studio 2010, on a Windows 8 system. I would like to change the auto-generated method header to include the developer name and current date to maintain header consistency with existing code. In other words, I would like the header to resemble something like the following:

```
''' Author.........: John Doe
''' Created........: 2/15/2007 2:25:30 PM
''' <summary>
''' 
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
```

I have tried to find out how to do this, and it seems that I need to edit a file located somewhere in the following directory: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates` but I have not been able to find a zipped folder that contains the method header file.

Am I looking in the correct place? What is the container's name I am supposed to be looking for? Finally, when I do find it, what do I need to add to make the date auto-generated for today's date?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to install GhostDoc, which can be downloaded from [here](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx). It is not exactly the solution that I was looking for, but it was close enough.